# Mongoose : update collection with previous data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning NodeJs and for a demo project i need to use MonGoDB with Mongoose.

I created a collection for a photo album.

The first row is : albumName and the second row is : pictures.

I don't undersand how i can save all my pictures in the row pictures without erasing old entries.

It will be awesome if i can work like this. So i can fetch all data (and pictures) of a album with one query :-)

the results must be an output like this :

```
{
    album : album1,
    pictures{
        1.jpg,
        2.jpg,
        3.jpg
    }
}
```

Actually, the update query for a album look like this :
I save big pictures and thumbnail pictures

```
uploader.on('end', function() {
  console.log("done uploading big pics");

  //SAVE DB
  AlbumPhoto.update({album:'album1'}, {$set: {pictures:file_name}}, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
});

uploader2.on('end', function() {
  console.log("done uploading mini pics");

  //SAVE DB
  AlbumPhoto.update({album:'album1'}, {$set: {pictures:mini}}, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
});
```

Someone can give me the directives and a example to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the schema you posted is off, should be

```
{
    album : "album1",
    pictures: [
        1.jpg,
        2.jpg,
        3.jpg
    ]
}
```

note "pictures" is an array not an object.

You can add to the array with

```
//SAVE DB

AlbumPhoto.update({album:'album1'}, {$push: {pictures: "new.jpg"}}, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now if i want to organise the array like this :`pictures:[1.jpg, 1-mini.jpg], [2.jpg, 2-mini.jpg] ...` how i can push that ?